# How do I recover from Mariadb(10.4.18) binlog corruption

Tags: mariadb

I have a 3 node Mariadb Galera cluster running Mariadb 10.4.18 on ubuntu 18.4.
I applied updates to one of the nodes this morning and now Mariadb doesn't start on that node with the following error.

[ERROR] I/O error reading the header from the binary log, errno=175, io cache code=0
[ERROR] I/O error reading the header from the binary log
[ERROR] Can't init tc log
[ERROR] Aborting'

2 or the 3 nodes are running and are up to date.

There are 5 items in the mariadb-bin.index file and all point to files that are 0 length.

I have searched the internet to find out how to recover from this but the advices seems to be rather limited. I have found the following:

https://www.webmaster2020.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2716
http://raafat.tawasol.net/mysql-crashes-io-error/

These suggest deleting the corrupt fail and restarting. Is this safe and the best way to recover from this?

Comment: `$ perror 175
MariaDB error code 175: File too short; Expected more data in file`
So its probably you rant out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Once it became clear that the cluster had been working properly right until the reboot, I restored the node to the last backup and let Galera bring the node back up to date.

In the end it was came back very quickly.